# How to find if my app is loading an Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

Having this in routes.rb

```
mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'
```

Since the ckeditor gem's controllers inherit from my ApplicationController, how can I find inside it that those are the controllers that are being loaded?

I need this because I found out that my ApplicationController is overriding the layout declaration and thus breaking the gem.

So far tried using `request.original_url` to check if "ckeditor" is present but it doesen't work out because when the engine is being loaded that part is 'ripped off'...

Answer (score 0):

Run `rake routes`. It tells you about the routes in mounted engines.

Comment: So you're suggesting that I should check occurrences of every single route defined in the engine? Does not seem practical at all.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case, there is a method `respond_with_asset` defined inside the engine's ApplicationController so I'm simply doing:

```
if defined? respond_with_asset
```